# HashMap with <ArrayList<String>> as a value, getting AnimalHipsters

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, hashmap

I have `network` and `favoriteAnimals`, it looks like this:
[image]

I have a function   `public ArrayList<String> findAnimalHipsters(HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> network,
            HashMap <String,String> favoriteAnimals)`

Which returns an ArrayList of Strings of people who are animal hipsters, meaning their ALL neighbour's animals must be different from my animal. For example, Dan has Quakka, and his neighbours, Lior and Rona, they all have different animals than Dan's animal. Thus, Dan is animal hipster. I need to return all the animal hipsters. Here's my implementation, I'm getting wrong output, it prints that all of the people are animal hipsters which is wrong.

**MainClass.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        NetWorkApp instance = new NetWorkApp();
        instance.CreateAnimals();
        instance.neighboursForPersons();
        ArrayList<String> animalHipsters = instance.findAnimalHipsters(instance.network, instance.favoriteAnimals);
        for(String st : animalHipsters)
            System.out.print(st + " ");
    }
}
```

**NetWorkApp.java**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NetWorkApp {

    public HashMap <String,String> favoriteAnimals;
    public HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> network;

    public NetWorkApp()
    {
        this.favoriteAnimals = new HashMap <String,String>();
        network = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    }

    public void CreateAnimals()
    {
        /*Adding elements to favoriteAnimals*/
        favoriteAnimals.put("Dan", "Quakka");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Ella", "Quakka");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Rona", "Dog");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Lior", "Cat");
        favoriteAnimals.put("David", "Dog");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Dor", "Dog");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Rina", "Quakka");
        favoriteAnimals.put("Gil", "Dog");
    }

    public void neighboursForPersons(){


        /*Creating neighbours for every person*/
        ArrayList<String> Dan = new ArrayList<String>();
        Dan.add("Rona");
        Dan.add("Lior");

        ArrayList<String> Ella = new ArrayList<String>();
        Ella.add("Rona");
        Ella.add("Dor");

        ArrayList<String> Rona = new ArrayList<String>();
        Rona.add("Dan");
        Rona.add("Ella");
        Rona.add("Lior");
        Rona.add("Dor");
        Rona.add("Rina");

        ArrayList<String> Lior = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lior.add("Dan");
        Lior.add("Rona");
        Lior.add("Dor");
        Lior.add("Gil");
        Lior.add("Rina");
        Lior.add("David");

        ArrayList<String> David = new ArrayList<String>();
        David.add("Lior");
        David.add("Gil");
        David.add("Rina");

        ArrayList<String> Dor = new ArrayList<String>();
        Dor.add("Ella");
        Dor.add("Rona");
        Dor.add("Rina");

        ArrayList<String> Rina = new ArrayList<String>();
        Rina.add("Dor");
        Rina.add("Rona");
        Rina.add("Lior");
        Rina.add("David");
        Rina.add("Gil");

        ArrayList<String> Gil = new ArrayList<String>();
        Gil.add("Lior");
        Gil.add("David");
        Gil.add("Rina");

        network.put("Dan", Dan);
        network.put("Ella", Ella);
        network.put("Rona", Rona);
        network.put("Lior", Lior);
        network.put("David", David);
        network.put("Dor", Dor);
        network.put("Rina", Rina);
        network.put("Gil", Gil);

    }

    public ArrayList<String> findAnimalHipsters(HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> network,
            HashMap <String,String> favoriteAnimals)
            {
        boolean found = false;
        ArrayList<String> animalHipsters = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Display elements
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : favoriteAnimals.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();

                    for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entrySecond : network.entrySet()){
                        if(key.equals(entrySecond.getKey())){
                            for(String st : entrySecond.getValue())
                            {
                                if((entry.getValue()).equals(st)) //Match
                                    found = true;
                            }
                            if(!found)
                                animalHipsters.add(key);
                            else 
                                found = !found;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return animalHipsters;  
            }
}
```

Edit: I figured that I'm not checking the animals with animals, but names of neighbours instead. trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem lies here:

```
for(String st : entrySecond.getValue())
{
     if((entry.getValue()).equals(st)) //Match
         found = true;
}
```

You are ignoring the value of the previous neighbors, so basically, so you are only effectively comparing if the last neighbor you added has the same favourite animal.

Part of the Collection interface (which an ArrayList implements), is the method [`contains(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) which will tell you if a Collection contains the Object.

Also, with nested loops like this it is sometimes to at least initially to pull out the key and value into more meaningful names - this will help to ensure you are comparing the correct values. Or alternatively adding comments at each point to help.

**EDIT**
As you mentioned, you are comparing animal to persons name so you need to get the secondEntry value (Neighbours name) and then get their favourite animal. Also you might be better using a keySet. Try this:

```
// Each person in the network
for(Set<String> name : network.keySet()) 
{
      boolean isHipster = false;
      // Get their neighbours
      ArrayList<String> neighbours = network.get(name);
      // Get their favourite animal
      String favAnimal = favouriteAnimals.get(name);
      for(String st : neighbours ) //Neighbours loop
      {
          // Get their neighbours favourite animal
          String neighboursFavAnimal = favouriteAnimals.get(st);
          // Compare
          if(favAnimal.equals(neighboursFavAnimal))
          {
              //is a hipster
              isHipster = true;
              //Stop comparing as doesnt matter anymore
              break;
          }   
      }
      // If isHipster is still false then add the name.
      if(!isHipster)
          animalHispters.add(name)
 }
```

Comment: I know Java Devil, I'm still trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Only problems should be spelling differences (maybe also accounting for null values) which should be easy enough for you to spot and fix.

Comment: I changed to `for (String entry : network.keySet())`. works well

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Java 8 features:

```
List<String> animalHipsters = new ArrayList<>();
network.forEach((person, neighbours) -> {
    String animal = favoriteAnimals.get(person);
    if (neighbours.stream().map(favoriteAnimals::get).noneMatch(animal::equals)) {
        animalHipsters.add(person);
    }
});
return animalHipsters;
```

Result I'm getting is `[Dan, Lior, Rina, Ella]`.

---

Important stuff, explained line by line:

```
network.forEach((person, neighbours) ->
```

This iterates over the `network` map. `person` is the key and `neighbours` is the value that matches that key, i.e. the actual neighbours of `person`.

```
String animal = favoriteAnimals.get(person);
```

Here we get the favorite animal of the current person.

```
if (neighbours.stream().map(favoriteAnimals::get).noneMatch(animal::equals))
```

This is the meaty line... We are streaming the current list of neighbours, and for each one of these neighbours (which are neighbours of the current `person`), we are converting him/her to his/her favorite animal via the `Stream.map` method (by getting the animal from the `favoriteAnimals` map). At the end, we are using the `Stream.noneMatch` method, which checks that none of the favorite animals of the neighbours is equal to the current person's favorite animal. In natural language, this line might be read as *if none of the current neighbours' favorite animal matches the current person's favorite animal...*

```
animalHipsters.add(person);
```

If the condition of the previous line is satisfied, we know that the current person is an animal hipster, so we add it to the result list.

Comment: Thank you Federico! I'm not familiar with Java 8 I guess, It is quite different. Didn't meet `::`, `stream().map`, `forEach( , ) -> ` yet. I will go over it again, Do you have a good reference for these? And sorry again for not accepting your answer.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Again, no worries. I write answers here not only for whom asks questions, but also for future visitors that might need to know how to solve the same problem you have today. So it's fine if you don't accept the answer because today you want a pre Java 8 solution. Cheers!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS as to where to start learning Java 8, the Java tutorial is always a good place